# Standalone script reports "MySQL server has gone away"; problem with my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2, my.cnf

I have a ruby script that requires 'mysql2' and uses query statements to mysql like
`@db.query("SELECT sname,id FROM streets where region_id=#{region["id"]}")`
but it reports me a error always like this:

```
main.rb:261:in `query': MySQL server has gone away (Mysql2::Error)
    from main.rb:261:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
    from main.rb:258:in `each'
    from main.rb:258:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from main.rb:254:in `each'
    from main.rb:254:in `block in <main>'
    from main.rb:253:in `loop'
    from main.rb:253:in `<main>'
```

The script on my Ubuntu is OK, however, my production environment is CentOS and on there I installed MySQL from source code. My Rails app run there is OK and it also requires 'mysql2', but when I run this script it fails.

I think the problem is related to my.cnf but I don't know how configure it.

Answer (score 2):

The mysql2 gem provides [an option](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#connection-options) to [reconnect](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#reconnecting-mysql-connections) to MySQL in the event that the connection goes away. Rather than updating your my.cnf file, update your gem's database.yml file to include the

```
  reconnect: true
```

option. This will ensure that the mysql2 gem will attempt to reconnect to MySQL when required.

Answer (score 1):

you call .query method directly on object @db... what exactly is this object?

I mean... if you are under Rails, you should call queries like:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("sql here")
```

I think it could be the cause, because Rails manages connection pool (eg. 5 established connections and every query goes to one of them, based on requests).

Anyway, if this is not the cause, then it can be that your mysql2 gem is compiled with different version of libmysqlclient.so library on the system...
Then when you try to do a query, it internally throws an error about incompatible protocol and disconnects...

Please check that your libmysqlclient.so and it's header files are of the same version...
Or if you don't have more versions of them installed...
and then please try to recompile mysql2 gem.

Hope this helps.
Regards, NoICE

Comment: I find 4 libmysqlclient.so.16                                          /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16
/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16
/root/mysql5.1/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16
which is used by rails? can I copy it recover each other?

Comment: I this case it uses the one that your system suggests it, on linux, this is done by "ldconfig" config files, on OS X, this is managed by "dyload"... But I don't remember how you can get which one it uses... However, they are all .16 (so they should theoretically be all the same) and you should use the one which is installed with your current installation of mysql server... Also look for libmysqlclient header files (.h). When you run gem install mysql2 --debug you should see which one it uses while compilling...

Comment: Btw, you have 4 of them but 1 is enough :) they should mostly be just symlinks to your current mysql install (but some of them could be 32bit and 64bit variants, uh)